# android studio kotlin save choice into temporary arraylist then access temporary arraylist

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

im new to android studio.

can someone please give me an example how to save the choices to temporary arraylist, then choose again from the temporary arraylist?

for example, there are 2 images to choose from on either side of the screen. once i choose either one, that image is saved into temp arraylist.

However, when i run this, it gives me null pointer exception where i am trying to access temp array.

my guess is because they are in oncreate method. how can i resolve the issue?
Thank you!!

```
var list = mutableListOf(R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4)
var temp: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.game)

        imageView1.setImageResource(list[0])
        imageView2.setImageResource(list[1])
        imageView1.setOnClickListener{
           temp.add(list[0])
        }
        imageView2.setOnClickListener{
           temp.add(list[0])
        }


        imageView1.setImageResource(list[2])
        imageView2.setImageResource(list[3])
        imageView1.setOnClickListener{
           temp.add(list[1])
        }
        imageView2.setOnClickListener{
           temp.add(list[1])
        }


        imageView1.setImageResource(temp[0]) // error here
        imageView2.setImageResource(temp[1])
        imageView1.setOnClickListener{
           textView.setText("Right Won")
        }
        imageView2.setOnClickListener{
           textView.setText("Left Won")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your `Activity` is created it runs that code, from top to bottom. You set click listeners which will add items to `temp` when the user clicks them, but that can't happen until after `onCreate` has finished running.

So when you get to the line with the error, a few nanoseconds later, you're trying to access the contents of `temp` but it's empty, right?

All your code at bottom looks like it should be run in response to the user clicking on something, not when the `Activity` is first created. You should put it in a separate function, called something like `checkResult` and call that from your click listeners, to check the result after the user clicks something!